# Where do I get a lottery ticket?

Tags: yo-kai-watch-2-fleshy-souls

I know I can redeem lottery tickets with the old woman in the candy shop, but she doesn't sell them. How can I get lottery tickets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it with a reasonable chance either from the rubbish bin in front the house near the Kuramoto village station, or from defeating かりパックン in the old lady's house, also in Kuramoto village. I'm not sure if it's called 'Kuramoto' in the English version, so here's an image.

[Source](http://xn--2wiki-bn4dva6qra1265hjep3ko8r3c.com/%E5%A6%96%E6%80%AA%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A9%E3%83%83%E3%83%812-%E4%B8%89%E8%A7%92%E3%81%8F%E3%81%98%E3%81%AE%E9%9B%86%E3%82%81%E6%96%B9%E3%81%A8%E3%83%AA%E3%82%BB%E3%83%9E%E3%83%A9%E3%81%AE%E3%82%84%E3%82%8A/)

[image: かりパックン]

Comment: You can also receive them at random events. I got one from someone on the train.